# how to GET url values after header function?

Tags: php

Peace be with you all,
I have a small problem which is i don't know how to store the values i get from a url using     `$_GET` method after using `header` function, here is the code so you can get what i am saying:-

i have index.php that has the link with the values:-

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='test.php?id=5&s=6'>Click Here</a> <br>"; 
?>
```

Here is test.php which is supposed to get the values from this url:-

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['id'])&&isset($_GET['s'])){
        echo $_GET['id'].$_GET['s'];
        header('location:test.php');
    }
?>
```

I don't know how to get the values from the url along with using the `header` function, i get them normally when i don't use the `header` function what can i do to store the variables to use them after redirecting using the `header` function? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use session variables to store variables across pages. At the top of each page add session_start()....to decare the session variable then do this:

```
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['s'])){
      $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
       header('location:test.php');
       exit;
     }
```

Now, on your test.php file, if you add the session_start at the top of the page you can access that variable: `$_SESSION['id']`.

Comment: @nFinlt_loop thank you so much dear, it is working nicely, but what if i wanna add another link with other values how can i get the values from both links using SESSION? 
like :-
 echo "<a href='test.php?id=5&s=6'>Click Here</a> <br>"; 
 echo "<a href='test.php?id=7&s=8'>Click Here</a> <br>"; 
i wanna click on the first link then get 5 and 6 and then click on the second link and get 7 and 8 with 5 and 6 ?

Comment: Now I am confused, you are doing a re-direct on the click event, so there wouldn't be a way to get values from two different <a> tags.

Comment: do i need to do like a for loop to accept consecutive sessions? i need something kinda similar to a shopping cart idea, i want to echo the values from each link i click on one after another, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You may be better off using jQuery...you could easily create an array if your id's from a click event.

Answer (score 0):

The `header('location:test.php');` redirects the page before you ever see the output.

Note: calling `header()` shouldn't work if you have already done any output with `echo`, so you must have some sort of output buffering going on. But the point is that you don't see your `echo` output because of the immediate redirect.

You should save them in `$_SESSION`, `$_COOKIE`, or a database if you need them later. Otherwise, they disappear when the script ends.

Comment: yes i get you but isn't there any way to store the values i get from the url to use them after the header function? the echo here is an example, i just wanna store these values to use them after redirecting, can i do that? thanks

Comment: The questions is how to store variables for later use.

Comment: @user2869402 See my edit. You need to save them to something that lasts, like the session data, a cookie, or a database.

Comment: @nFinIt_loop Good point; I didn't understand quite what OP meant at first. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are redirecting to ``test.php you can send those variables to the next page using

```
header('location:test.php?id=' . $_GET['id'] . '&s=' . $_GET['s']);
```

Then from your `test.php` file you can use

```
if( isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['s']) ) {
    echo $_GET['id'] . ' ' . $_GET['s'];
}
```

Also, you can use `session` to store those for subsequent requests, check [Basic usage of session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: akhy this will loop forever

Answer (score 0):

An option is to resend the variables:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['s'])){
    echo $_GET['id'].$_GET['s'];
    header('location:test.php?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
```

Be aware of a loop here...

Comment: this will loop forever also